# C++ Create a new array off of some values of std::vector?

Tags: c++

**I know what I am doing here is horribly wrong:**

```
void Example( void )
{
    // DECLARE LOCAL VARIABLES
    ::UINT nPosition = 5;
    ::UINT nLength = 5;
    std::vector< ::UINT >vn_VectorA;
    ::UINT *an_ArrayA = new ::UINT[ nLength ];

    // FILL vn_VectorA WITH DECIMAL VALUE OF "HelloWorld!!!"
    // I KNOW THIS IS AN UGLY WAY OF DOING IT. BUT FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES,
    // I CAN CARELESS.
    vn_VectorA.push_back( 72 );     // H
    vn_VectorA.push_back( 101 );    // e
    vn_VectorA.push_back( 108 );    // l
    vn_VectorA.push_back( 108 );    // l
    vn_VectorA.push_back( 111 );    // o
    vn_VectorA.push_back( 87 );     // W
    vn_VectorA.push_back( 111 );    // o
    vn_VectorA.push_back( 114 );    // r
    vn_VectorA.push_back( 108 );    // l
    vn_VectorA.push_back( 100 );    // d
    vn_VectorA.push_back( 33 );     // !
    vn_VectorA.push_back( 33 );     // !
    vn_VectorA.push_back( 33 );     // !

    // Copy the desire values of vn_VectorA to an_ArrayA
    for( ::UINT nCopyIndex = nPosition, nArrayAIndex = 0; nArrayAIndex != nLength; nArrayAIndex ++, nCopyIndex ++ )
    {
        an_ArrayA[ nArrayAIndex ] = vn_VectorA[ nCopyIndex ];
#ifdef DEBUG
        std::cout << an_ArrayA[ nArrayAIndex ] << ' ';
#endif // DEBUG
    }
};
```

**This is what I use to copy certain values of a std::vector:**

```
    // Copy the desire values of vn_VectorA to an_ArrayA
    for( ::UINT nCopyIndex = nPosition, nArrayAIndex = 0; nArrayAIndex != nLength; nArrayAIndex ++, nCopyIndex ++ )
    {
        an_ArrayA[ nArrayAIndex ] = vn_VectorA[ nCopyIndex ];
#ifdef DEBUG
        std::cout << an_ArrayA[ nArrayAIndex ] << ' ';
#endif // DEBUG
    }
```

After running the code, it should print:
87 111 114 108 100

So, how should I be doing this???

Comment: Why are you using both `vector` and a pointer to dynamic array?

Comment: Anyway, it's printing those numbers for me: http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0a2bbce5555165d16f98b0759b7b7e99 What's the problem?

Comment: Well, I could just use std::vector but I thought it would take less memory and more efficient if I just use a dynamic array to hold just some part of the std::vector instead of making a new std::vector to hold those value. I am wrong, right?

Comment: @Pubby Yeah it works. However, I believe that there is a better and a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: @CLearner Yes, you are wrong. There may be some corner cases where you'd actually use dynamic arrays instead of vectors, but only if you have conclusive evidence that this is the bottleneck in your program!

Comment: @CLearner No, you're not. If you want to share the data and avoid an allocation then just use a pointer or index to the vector, although for such small data it's probably pointless.

Comment: @CLearner: Yes, you are wrong. `std::vector` is efficient as basic array.

Comment: "*I CAN CARELESS*" - This makes no sense. Perhaps you mean "I CAN BE CARELESS" or "I CAN NOT CARE LESS". :)

Comment: @Robᵩ all wrong. I made a typo, so what? I can care less*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use std::copy?

```
std::copy(&*vn_Vector.begin() + nPosition, &*vn_Vector.end(), an_ArrayA);
```

Note that I'm only dereferencing vn_Vector.end() so it has the same type as &*vn_Vector.begin() + nPosition.

Comment: The `&*` isn't necessary. The input and output iterators can have different types.

Comment: **Adjusted your answer to**..................................................................... .......................................               std::copy( vn_VectorA.begin( ) + nPosition, vn_VectorA.begin( ) + nLength + nPosition, an_ArrayA ); @john.pavan thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is mainly based on @john.pavan's answer.

```
#pragma region DOCUMENTATION ON: STD_COPY_VECTOR_TO_ARRAY
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// MACRO: STD_COPY_VECTOR_TO_ARRAY( Vector, Position, Length, Array )       //
//                                                                          //
// DESCRIPTION:                                                             //
// A defined macro that is created to copy selected values of std::vector   //
// an array. This defined macro takes 4 arguments.                          //
//                                                                          //
// ARGUMENTS:                                                               //
// Vector - The std::vector that contains the values that will be copied.   //
// Position - Position of the first value from Vector to be copied.         //
// Note: The first value of Position is marked by the value of 0 and not 1. //
// Length - Amount of values to be copied from Vector.                      //
// Array - The Array that the values will be copied to.                     //
//                                                                          //
// TIPS:                                                                    //
// #1 - To copy all values within Vector, set the value of Position to 0    //
// and set the value of Length to the size of Vector (std::vector::size).   //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma endregion
#define STD_COPY_VECTOR_TO_ARRAY( Vector, Position, Length, Array )         \
                                  std::copy( Vector.begin( ) + Position,    \
                                  Vector.begin( ) + Position + Length ,     \
                                  Array )
```